# Multiple Notes in single call

Tags: php, evernote

I am using PHP library to make calls to Evernote API. I use [findNotesMetaData](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_findNotesMetadata) to get list of notes but the response does not include Note's content/excerpt or thumbnail. So I have to make separate calls to [getNote](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getNote) to get content or thumbnail.

Is it possible to get content/excerpt or thumbnail in single call? The reason why I am asking is because if there are many notes, getting each note by calling [getNote](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getNote) will take significant amount of time!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can't retrieve all the notes' content in a single call. If your app needs all the copy of user's notes, it might be better to think about implementing [Full Sync](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/synchronization.php). You also have to take [rate limit](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/rate_limits.php) into consideration.